# Incorrect line thickness in the exported PDF

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format

The code below plots and exports to a PDF file. As one can see, there is a clear difference between the plotted line thickness in the notebook (left) and in the PDF snapshot (right). This is a sister question of [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/286714). The phenomenon looks similar but the context/workaround is not that related at least apparently.

```
mydata = 
  Table[Sin[x + y^2], {x, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/100}, {y, 
    0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/100}];
plot = With[{blplot = 
    ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 0.06^2, {x, -0.1, 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}, 
     ContourStyle -> {Blue, Dashed, Thickness[0.013]}], 
   mainplot = 
    ListDensityPlot[mydata, DataRange -> 0.08 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{0.08 {-1, 1}, None}, {0.08 {-1, 1}, None}}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[15], PlotRange -> Full]}, 
  Show[mainplot, blplot, ImageSize -> 205]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Test2.pdf"}], plot, 
  ImageResolution -> 300];
```

[image]

And we have very similar observations to those in the linked question.

- There is some threshold thickness between 0.013 and 0.014, where the PDF line thickness suddenly changes.
- Double the `imagesize` may occasionally get this issue away, but this is not what is wanted. For other reasons like file size and screen size, I need to keep such an image size.
- Right-clicking the image and saving it as PDF is not a desired solution, either.
- Tuning `ImageResolution` does not help. Removing this option sometimes may get it right, but in other more complicated plots this will make the PDF file outrageously large or just freeze the program.

Is there any remedy for this?

### Edit1

Using `AbsoluteThickness` helps for replacing `Thickness[0.013]` by `AbsoluteThickness[0.013 imagesize]`, but does not work for (relative) `Thickness` below or equal to 0.01.

### Edit2

Thanks to the comments by @Michael E2, the cause of this whole thickness issue is believed to be 'VertexColors' used by `ListDensityPlot`. However, it is not yet clear how to work this around in the present case.

Comment: Try `AbsoluteThickness[t*i]` where `t` is the relative thickness and `i` is the `ImageSize`. -- I'm pretty sure this is the same bug (the particular renderer invoke). That `DensityPlot` invokes it instead of `VertexColors` does not distinguish this significantly to my mind. E.g. `FreeQ[plot, VertexColors]` shows that `DensityPlot` is using `VertexColors`. And `Export[FileNameJoin[{"/tmp", "Test2.pdf"}], 
 DeleteCases[plot, _[VertexColors, _List], Infinity], 
 ImageResolution -> 300]` yields a PDF with appropriate thickness.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Similar to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286714/line-thickness-out-of-control-in-exported-pdf#comment714064_286811), `AbsoluteThickness` does not work below 0.01 here. And the `DeleteCases` command gives a PDF losing the entire plot except the dashed line. (Or maybe you only intend to show the relevance to `VertexColors`?)   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$   In any case, we still need a workaround here.

Comment: "Or maybe you only intend to show the relevance to VertexColors?" Right. :)

Comment: ".... does not work below 0.01" -- This is an old bug with PDF rasterization, I believe. I've run into it, pre-Stackexchange, IIRC. Something like less than `AbsoluteThickness[2.5]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 'not working below 0.01 is an old bug with PDF rasterization' I still doubt it. In the earlier question, as long as we do not use `VertexColors`, the PDF works fine all the way down to the minimal recognizable thickness, far below `AbsoluteThickness[2.5]`.

Comment: `VertexColors` invokes **rasterization**, which is where the bug lies. `DensityPlot` colors the plot with `VertexColors`. `VertexColors` is why the plot is rasterized, the same in both questions. The main difference to the user is that points can be colored by other means. Polygons cannot be gradient-colored except by use of `VertexColors`. Again, the base problem is the same in both cases.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the explanation. I totally agree that the base issue is the same one. And I see your logic more clearly. Now we only need a workaround for this `DensityPlot`.